# Java method not being run correctly in Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, simulink

I am using a **Level 2 S Function** written in **Matlab 2018** to handle input from a **Simulink** model. Depending on that input, an image(made with Swing) moves across the screen.

**For example**, "10" makes it move left and "01" right.

I used **Java 1.8** to create a `Game` class to handle the image movement. I need to pass the data to an instance of the Java object, so I created a method in the class to take the input values and move the image on the screen, called `getMdlValues`. `moveDiver` is the public method used in Matlab to call `getMdlValues`.

I create the object in the S function's `Start` function and grab it in the `Update` function using `set_param` and `get_param`. I then try to call   `getMdlValues` via `moveDiver`. However, nothing happens on screen. The image does not move, even though the print statements I put in the method are executing.

Part of the Matlab code for reference :

```
function Start(block)

    gameObj = javaObject('frenchToast.lafayette.edu.Game'); % object 

    set_param(block.BlockHandle,'UserData',gameObj);
    %javaMethodEDT('main',gameObj,""); %test
    gameObj.main("");

%end Start

function Update(block)


    gameObj = get_param(block.BlockHandle,'UserData'); %get object

    javaMethod('moveDiver',gameObj, 1,0); %move image to the left

%end Update
```

I have tried `javaObjectEDT` and `javaMethodEDT` but they did not work- the image did not move. Perhaps I have to make a Runnable? I did not try that and I do not know how to. I have verified that the method `getMdlValues` works when not calling it in Matlab(I ran the class in Eclipse and the method moved the image of the diver). In Matlab, I passed it "10" and it printed "left" to the window. So it runs the code but it does not update the position of my image. Why? Can Matlab not manipulate Swing objects within my Game class?

Partial code in Game.class :

```
//create scuba diver image
        scuba = new JLabel("");
        scuba.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\frenchToast\\Downloads\\scuba75.png"));
        scuba.setBounds(285, 537, 75, 44);
        panel.add(scuba);
```

Much later in the code :

```
public void moveDiver(boolean left, boolean right) {

        getMdlValues(left,right);
}


private void getMdlValues(boolean left, boolean right) { //used to analyze values from Simulink 

        System.out.println("testing getMdlValues");

        if(!chestDirection.equals("")){ //don't do anything unless start menu has been closed

            if(left == true && right == false) { //left
                scuba.setLocation(scuba.getX() - 5, scuba.getY());
                System.out.println("left");
            }

            else if(left == false && right == true) { //right
                scuba.setLocation(scuba.getX() + 5, scuba.getY());
                System.out.println("right");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Left and Right values unable to be determined or do not move"); 
            }

            checkScored(); //see if scuba diver found the treasure
        }
}
```

I really appreciate any time and help given! Please let me know if you need any more(or less) detail.